# Count rows each month of a year - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table "**Product**" as :

```
| ProductId  | ProductCatId | Price  |      Date    |   Deadline   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |      1       |  10.00 |   2016-01-01 |  2016-01-27  |
|     2      |      2       |  10.00 |   2016-02-01 |  2016-02-27  |
|     3      |      3       |  10.00 |   2016-03-01 |  2016-03-27  |
|     4      |      1       |  10.00 |   2016-04-01 |  2016-04-27  |
|     5      |      3       |  10.00 |   2016-05-01 |  2016-05-27  |
|     6      |      3       |  10.00 |   2016-06-01 |  2016-06-27  |   
|     7      |      1       |  20.00 |   2016-01-01 |  2016-01-27  |
|     8      |      2       |  30.00 |   2016-02-01 |  2016-02-27  |
|     9      |      1       |  40.00 |   2016-03-01 |  2016-03-27  |
|     10     |      4       |  15.00 |   2016-04-01 |  2016-04-27  |
|     11     |      1       |  25.00 |   2016-05-01 |  2016-05-27  |
|     12     |      5       |  55.00 |   2016-06-01 |  2016-06-27  |
|     13     |      5       |  55.00 |   2016-06-01 |  2016-01-27  |
|     14     |      5       |  55.00 |   2016-06-01 |  2016-02-27  |
|     15     |      5       |  55.00 |   2016-06-01 |  2016-03-27  |
```

I want to create SP count rows of Product each month with condition Year = CurrentYear , like :

```
| Month| SumProducts | SumExpiredProducts |
-------------------------------------------
|   1  |      3      |         3          |
|   2  |      3      |         3          |
|   3  |      3      |         3          |
|   4  |      2      |         2          |
|   5  |      2      |         2          |
|   6  |      2      |         2          |
```

What should i do ?

Comment: What about different years? E.g. date 2017-01-01?

Comment: Where is the SumExpiredProducts coming from?

Comment: It's a example , It doesn't mean .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT MONTH([Date]), 
       COUNT(*) AS SumProducts ,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Date] > Deadline THEN 1 END) AS SumExpiredProducts 
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH([Date])
```